# Return an array of structs for a specific condition

Tags: arrays, struct

I would like to know if it is possible to create a function that would return an array of structs for a specific condition. Let's consider this for the following contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract Trips {
    struct Trip {
        bytes20 id;
        address creator;
        uint256 createdAt;
        string destination;
    }

    Trip[] public tripsArray;
    
    function addTrip (string memory _destination) external {
        bytes20 id = bytes20(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.timestamp)));
        Trip memory trip = Trip({
            id: id,
            creator: msg.sender,
            createdAt: block.timestamp,
            destination: _destination
        });
        tripsArray.push(trip);
    }
}
```

How could I construct a function that would return an array of trips that a function caller address has created?

Edit:

I could think of the following solution however it is not ideal because it creates empty records in the array:

```
    function getTripsToAddress() public view returns (Trip[] memory) {
        Trip[] memory tripsForAddress = new Trip[](tripsArray.length);
          for (uint i = 0; i < tripsArray.length; i++) {
              if (tripsArray[i].creator == msg.sender) {
                  tripsForAddress[i] = tripsArray[i];
              }
              }
              return tripsForAddress;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem is to first initialize the array of trips that will be returned to have a length equal to the number of trips that were created by the function caller, and then iterate over the `tripsArray` to filter out the trips that were not created by the function caller.

Here is an example of how the `getTripsToAddress` function could be implemented:

```
function getTripsToAddress() public view returns (Trip[] memory) {
    // Count the number of trips that were created by the function caller
    uint count = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < tripsArray.length; i++) {
        if (tripsArray[i].creator == msg.sender) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Initialize the array of trips to return with the correct length
    Trip[] memory tripsForAddress = new Trip[](count);

    // Iterate over the tripsArray again, this time only adding the trips that were created by the function caller to the tripsForAddress array
    uint j = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < tripsArray.length; i++) {
        if (tripsArray[i].creator == msg.sender) {
            tripsForAddress[j] = tripsArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return tripsForAddress;
}
```

Note that this solution avoids creating empty records in the array, as it only initializes the `tripsForAddress` array with the correct length and adds only the trips that were created by the function caller to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getArr() public view returns (Trip [] memory)
return tripsArray;
```

Comment: Thanks but this will return the entire array, while I only want to return records that a function caller address has created.

Comment: To achieve that You need mapping